# Is it possible to have a loading spinner in p-table as it does with lazyLoading in p-table

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a plain p-table prime-ng component, which does not implement lazy loading.
My code looks like below,

```
<div  class="row" *ngIf="(notificationDashboardLi && notificationDashboardLi.length > 0) " style="padding:10px;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p-table #dt [value]="notificationDashboardLi" [columns]="cols" [paginator]="true" [rows]="rowsPerPage" 
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="rowsPerPageOptions" [responsive]="true" dataKey="id">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>.............</tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr>..........</tr>
        </ng-template> 
         <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-expanded="expanded">
            <tr>...</tr> 
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have loading in this table with header getting displayed but table showing loading spinner until table totally loads? I am able to do it for the whole table but not after the header template.

I am using this code bwfore the entire div and it works fine.

```
<div [ngSwitch]='status'>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'loading'" style="padding:5px;padding-left:40%"><div class="loader"></div></div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'active'">   ....
</div>
```

What i am actually looking is to display this spinner after the table header. Is it possible? TIA.
Note: I was able to get this loading work with p-table that implements lazy loading. But i have a page with another table which doesnt use lazy loading. Is it possible here?